# Java how to create Not clickable Jlist

Tags: java, swing, colors, jlist

[image]

this image is taken from netbean, the option 1. and 2. is not clickable.
I have the similiar setup in Jlist but when i setenabled(false) the item become grey, i want it remain black color, like what is shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this image is taken from netbean, the option 1. and 2. is not
>   clickable. I have the similiar setup in Jlist but when i
>   setenabled(false) the item become grey, i want it remain black color,
>   like what is shown above.

for disabled `JList` you can to change key in `UIManager.put("Label.disabledForeground", Color.magenta);`

EDIT

you can to play with

```
UIManager.put("List.background", Color.lightGray);
UIManager.put("List.selectionBackground", Color.orange);
UIManager.put("List.selectionForeground", Color.blue);
UIManager.put("Label.disabledForeground", Color.magenta);
```

or similair methods is possible to override in `XxxListCellRenderer` too, without set any value to `UIManager`